# VirtualBox 4.3.12, Windows 7 as guest and host OS: host -> guest clipboard not working

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, clipboard

I use [VirtualBox 4.3.12 r93733](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.12/).

- Guest OS: Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate
- Host OS: Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate

I installed the VirtualBox Guest Additions and rebooted the guest OS. The host -> guest clipboard is not working, is there any way to fix this issue? Host -> guest clipboard means that I copy something in their keyboard in the host OS and try to paste it in the guest OS.

The guest -> host clipboard works fine. I set the clipboard to be bidirectional:

[image]

[image]

The VirtualBox Guest Additions are running fine on the guest OS:

[image]

I restarted [`VBoxTray.exe`](http://www.wintips.org/how-to-fix-oracle-virtualbox-copy-paste-clipboard-windows/) but it didn't help. I also try giving administrative permission to this process.

Before upgrading VirtualBox (I believe I had 4.3.6) the bidirectional clipboard was working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to do one step more, when you start your window 7, you will see menus at top.

```
click on Devices -> shared Clipboard -> Bidirectional
```

now you can copy and paste from host to guest or gues to host

Comment: Thanks, I think that's the same setting but I had also done it in case, see updated question.

Comment: it should work then

Comment: Well, yeah I agree :(

Comment: try to remove the os from virtualbox and load it again

Comment: Interesting, it does work after killing the VM and creating a new one... I don't understand why one needs to do so, but whatever :)

Comment: Did not work for me.