# How to copy/paste from windows clipboard to ubuntu in virtualbox?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, clipboard

I am currently configuring ubuntu in virtualBox. When i am trying to copy from windows clipboard to ubuntu, i couldn't.

I installed Guest additions and also changed the "Shared clipboard" option to "Bidirectional". But i am not able to do achieve.

How can we resolve this?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/835157/virtualbox-4-3-12-windows-7-as-guest-and-host-os-host-guest-clipboard-not-w