# Bidirectional clipboard not working in VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, centos, clipboard

I'm using VirtualBox Version 5.2.6 r120293 (Qt5.6.1).

**Guest OS:** Windows 7 Ultimate (32-bit)
**Host OS:** CentOS 7

I tried enabling bidirectional clipboard by going to **Settings -> General -> Advanced** and selecting **Bidirectional** form the dropdown menu for **shared clipboard**.

[image]

Then I restarted the machine. But it wasn't working.

I have already tried removing and adding the VM to the machine list. But the problem persists.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed the Guest Additions on the Windows 7 guest?

Comment: @n8te I don't think so. Can you guide me to it?

Comment: The guest additions are required to be able to use the bidirectional clipboard so that should be the cause of your issue if you don't remember installing it. See [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VirtualBox 4.3.12, Windows 7 as guest and host OS: host -> guest clipboard not working](https://superuser.com/questions/835157/virtualbox-4-3-12-windows-7-as-guest-and-host-os-host-guest-clipboard-not-w)

Comment: @n8te Guest additions weren't installed. So, I installed that and the bidirectional clipboard started working. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't write an answer. But I've had the same issue with Guest Additions 6.1.4. The extension is buggy, so there is no (easy) solution, but as a workaround, just downgrade to the last version. In my case, it just worked after I've downloaded GA 6.1.2. Now I can work as I'm used to and wait for the bug to be fixed.

Comment: This is a known issue with VirtualBox Guest Additions. Downgrade or get trunk release. Here you have test builds for 5.2: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds

See: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19336

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot write an answer (just made an account), but I resolved this issue on my system (windows 10 host, linux vm, using 6.1.12). The extension_pack was actually installed and setup on my system (maybe newer version do it automatically), however the GUEST Addtions was not, and needed to be added. In the same site/area you download the extension_pack, you can also download guestadditions.iso. Installation is easy, mount it on the optical drive (I did it from settings), open terminal: cd /media/(yourusername)/VBox_GAs_6.1.12, and then type: sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run

Comment: anyone with 6.1.14? done all things. both answers also comment. none of em works. help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't clipboard sharing work with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS inside VirtualBox 5.1.26?](https://superuser.com/questions/1318231/why-doesnt-clipboard-sharing-work-with-ubuntu-18-04-lts-inside-virtualbox-5-1-2)

Comment: This always fails after some time and I need to restart the OS to make it work again... it is a long existing bug.

Comment: 2023 reporting in: just got this to work in VBox Debian 11 running Raspberry Pi Desktop. 1. Installed the Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-7.0.10.vbox-extpack (my version of VBox, from @Ravi's answer below). Note: Ravi doesnt have this next part: 2. Install the VBox Guest Additons for Linux. 2.1 VBox > Devices >  Insert Guest Additions CD image. 2.2. Terminal > cp /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run. 2.3 Terminal > sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run 2.4 ??? 2.5 Profit 2.6. copy paste like a bahws

Answer (score 23):

You need to add extension pack for you virtualbox

1. Open https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox and open your Virtualbox version
2. Download **Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack.vbox-extpack**.
3. Open Virtualbox VM Manager
4. In **File->Preferences**, Select **Extension**
5. Now add extension by browsing to download location

Done.

Comment: It didn't work for me !

Comment: none of the "solutions" provided here work for me .
I have the Share clopboard bidireccional active, + guest additions CD installed + the Extension pack installed, still no clipboard exchange between a linux box (guest) an the Windows 10 (host)

Comment: did not work for me either Windows 10 host, Debian 10 amd 64 client

Comment: Seems broken in 6.1.4... can't get it to work with Kali Linux rolling. Additions installed version 6.1.4 from APT repo. Something broke in the last few months.

Comment: Although I have windows 10 for me work this answer https://superuser.com/questions/1318231/why-doesnt-clipboard-sharing-work-with-ubuntu-18-04-lts-inside-virtualbox-5-1-2

Comment: No its not broken! just download the proper version of VBoxGuestAdditions.iso from https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox and install on your vm.

Comment: @AminNadimi same here. i have 6.1.4e136177 installed (which is the exact same number as my vbox). it worked before. it doesn't work any more. is there another version you can confirm working? or any other proven way to make it work again?

Comment: @devman I have virtual box version 6.1.4 but installed [this version of iso file](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.0_RC1/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.0_RC1.iso), install it in your vm maybe this works for you either. After installation restart virtual box and also keep in mind that it will not share files in clip board! it only shares text as much as i saw.

Comment: This is a known issue with VirtualBox Guest Additions. Downgrade or get trunk release. Here you have test builds for 5.2: virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds See: virtualbox.org/ticket/19336

Comment: Yes, it was broken in 6.1.4. Today I installed 6.1.6 and also the guest additions and clipboard is working (after reboot)

Comment: it works on VBox 6.1

Comment: It did not work for me until I also installed the VBox guest additions then restarted the VM

Comment: NOTE: After doing this and installing guest additions, you'll need to restart the VM

Comment: @AminNadimi it's not working even after restarting. otherwise no complaint on this answer

Comment: I needed to install `VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.30.iso` on Guest OS found here : https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.30/

Comment: Why on earth you would need to add an extension to make work options that appear in the UI of the normal version infuriates me. While I've no doubt this is a fix, surely this was not by design?

Comment: Of course didn't work for me either. VirtualBox is such a trainwreck, it's almost unreal. I give up. I'm typing out ssh keys, passwords and URLs from now on, much quicker than doing a three hour detour everytime I want to do something that works elsewhere out of the box

Answer (score 12):

***This answer assumes:***

1. VBox extension pack is installed and current.
2. VBox guest additions are installed and current.

There is a suggestion in the comments to downgrade the guest additions in order to get the shared clipboard working. Although that may work, I solved this by taking the opposite approach. Unfortunately, if you're dealing with a new version of Virtualbox, full guest support may not quite be available. You can actually download and install guest additions that are *newer* than the bundled or released version.

Head to [VirtualBox test builds](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds), and in the top table, you will find the latest version of the guest additions. Compare your revision with the version listed, if it's newer simply download and install it.

If all else fails, uninstall the guest additions and reinstall them.

**Windows Guest:** Control Panel
**Linux Guest:** sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run uninstall

*The guest additions are specifically what provide shared clipboard support.* Take a look at the [virtualbox documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) to learn what other functionality they provide.

Comment: I had the extension pack, but was missing the guest additions.  Adding that resolved this issue for me.

Comment: I too started having the issue with Lubuntu 18.04 guest on a Ubuntu 20.04 host (both are 64-bit) with bundled Virtual Box 6.1.10. Just installed 6.1.14 along with Extension Pack and Guest Additions (the same versions 6.1.14), then the issue gone. Thanks a lot for the tips.

Comment: Had the same issue with OpenSUSE Leap 15.2 after upgrading the virtualbox package. Had to re-install guest additions.

Comment: great, thanks. 6.14 guestExt wasn`t working for me, but 6.17 testbuild did

Comment: @torno i had the same 6.14. it says i need to reinstall everything. really?

Comment: @AbdullahSaid can`t remember reinstalling everything. just used 6.17 guestExt instead

Answer (score 3):

I realized that VM doesn't recognize the clipboard data from some specific applications (like in my case Foxit PDF reader).

To workaround,

1. I copy the data from the application to a default location like notepad or even in the start menu search bar.
2. Then again I copy the text from that notepad/start-menu where I pasted it.
3. Then when I go into my VM and pasting it works.

[image: Image showing the second copy of data at start-menu that works for me]

Comment: lifesaver! thanks