# What is the version of Guest Addtions for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS inside VirtualBox 6.16 with Windows 10 Host?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, clipboard

I accepted the offered update to VirtualBox-6.1.16-140961-Win.exe on the host (Windows 10 /64)  I quickly noticed the the clipboard no longer worked between the host and guest.

I followed the steps in the [prior thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1318231/why-doesnt-clipboard-sharing-work-with-ubuntu-18-04-lts-inside-virtualbox-5-1-2), but they did not get the clipboard to work.

I thought an update to Guest Additions might be required too. I had to search around because a corresponding version of GA ISO was not available at https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/.
I found VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.19-142299.iso under [test builds](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds).
I mounted it, ran the autorun installer, and rebooted the guest as instructed.

This broke the system, leaving the guest VM unresponsive to mouse or keyboard. I restored the VM to a prior backup.

What is the necessary version of GA for VirtualBox-6.1.16?  Where is it found? What is the correct process for installing? Is it just the autorun, or are there also some terminal commands required?