# ubuntu server image blue screened

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ubuntu-server

Would anyone have a tip for running a virtual box ubuntu server image?

Setting up the virtual box image seemed to go just fine, updated ok, and I did a few reboots. What I wanted to get to work was being able to copy & paste from host operating system into this guest VM but now I am running into a blue screen when I boot it up.

I did do [this process](https://superuser.com/questions/1318231/why-doesnt-clipboard-sharing-work-with-ubuntu-18-04-lts-inside-virtualbox-5-1-2) when I was trying to setup the copy paste and it seems like after this everything went blue. First answer for this post:

> The problem is with the virtualbox-guest-x11 package missing

Would anyone have any tips to try? Sorry not on expert here in linux or virtual box... My ultimate goal is to be able to SSH into this VM running ubuntu server image. This is all that comes up when I log into the VM:

[image]

***UPDATE FOR SCREENSHOT***
[image]

[THESE STEPS WORKED TO GET SSH SETUP](https://dev.to/yassineselllami/how-to-ssh-into-ubuntu-vm-virtualbox-from-host-machine-1kii) from my Windows Host to the Ubuntu server VM

Comment: Even if you have no GPU out, you should be able to ssh in if its set up. You don't need a GUI to run linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution is a little long but will work. Start a new VM, access the terminal then type `sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms` then while the machine is still running `Go to devices > Add VirtualBox GuestImage` and then a window will pop up and follow the process. Then shut down the machine and go to VM settings. There enable boot only from the disk not from optical drive or anything else (it should be under storage but check other places too) and restart. Now you should be able to Copy-Paste, Resize etc.If you get an error comment below.

Comment: Any change could elaborate more about `Go to devices > Add VirtualBox GuestImage` would this be in the screenshot I added on my post under UPDATE FOR SCREENSHOT

Comment: Yes, it is in the last row under `Devices` you can see `Insert Guest Additions CD Image`.